# Map nested JSON object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, jsx

I spend few hours trying to figure this one out, and completely failed. I need your help.

I have a JSON file that I want to loop though and create a UI that has multiple columns that have multiple groups that have various numbers of items.

JSON file

```
{
"stuff": "content",
"stuff": "content",
"List" : [
  {
    "column" : [
      {
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 1" },
          { "name" : "item 2" }
        ],
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 3" },
          { "name" : "item 4" },
          { "name" : "item 5" },
          { "name" : "item 6" }
        ],
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 7" },
          { "name" : "item 8" },
          { "name" : "item 9" },
          { "name" : "item 10" }
        ],
      }
    ],
    "column" : [
      {
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 11" },
          { "name" : "item 12" },
          { "name" : "item 13" },
          { "name" : "item 14" }
        ],
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 15" },
          { "name" : "item 16" },
        ],
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 17" },
          { "name" : "item 18" },
          { "name" : "item 18" },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

And the react component:

```
import Data from 'data.json'

...
    {Data.List.map((columnItem, index) => (
      <div className="column">
        {columnItem.column.map((groupItem, index) => (
        <div className="group">
          {groupItem.group.map((item, index) => (
            <div>
              {item.name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
...
```

The issue is that I'm getting only one item in return.
It feels to me that I'm approach the problem completely the wrong the way by using .map
Any thoughts? I would appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0):

Data is corrupt. you have duplicate key data.

```js
{
  "stuff": "content",
    "stuff": "content",
    "List" : [
      {
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 1" },
          { "name" : "item 2" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group" : [
          { "name" : "item 11" },
          { "name" : "item 12" },
          { "name" : "item 13" },
          { "name" : "item 14" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you have the same keys more than onetime in each object the later keys override the previous one so the second `column` object override the previous `column` object the same is true for `group` key you can demonstrate this by printing `Data` object:

```js
let data={stuff:"content",stuff:"content",List:[{column:[{group:[{name:"item 1"},{name:"item 2"}],group:[{name:"item 3"},{name:"item 4"},{name:"item 5"},{name:"item 6"}],group:[{name:"item 7"},{name:"item 8"},{name:"item 9"},{name:"item 10"}]}],column:[{group:[{name:"item 11"},{name:"item 12"},{name:"item 13"},{name:"item 14"}],group:[{name:"item 15"},{name:"item 16"}],group:[{name:"item 17"},{name:"item 18"},{name:"item 18"}]}]}]};
// open the dev tool to see the table
console.table(data)
```

Comment: How can I loop over the keys without specifying their names? (this list is dynamic, reason why I tried to use the same names for keys).

Comment: you will always end up with the same cascaded `Data` object unless you use different names for the keys.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how would you render the react component if I were to use different names for the keys?